# Adobe Acrobat PDF textbox too small

Tags: fonts, adobe-acrobat, font-size

I've been using Adobe Acrobat 10.1.16 to add a text box in a PDF file, by using Tools -> Content -> Add or Edit Text Box. However, the largest size is 24, which is still too small. Is there anyway to add bigger text?

Comment: If you are on Mac, it is true that the Edit PDF component of Acrobat 10 is not very good (to say it nicely). If you would upgrade to Acrobat Pro DC, you'd have a much better Edit PDF component, and you would not need to do that overly complicated suggestion provided by another "expert".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use a text program to edit a sample text, like TexEdit if you are a
  Mac user

[image: textEdit]

- Export this sample text as a PDF file
- Open this *sample text* PDF file in Acrobat and go to **Content** > **Edit Document Text**, to change it

[image: edit text]

- Once done, select the text frame with **Edit Object** > Copy and Paste it in the other PDF file
- Relocate it and scale it if necessary with the **Edit Object** selector tool

[image: new text]

- Go back to the *Sample Text* PDF and replace the text to copy/paste and have a new text content

**Important:** before pasting verify that nothing is selected, because the new object pasted will replace the selection